# How know how min/hours in win per day

Tags: average

I didn't know if i can post this here but i want to know a mathematical formula:

On a dryer there are 4 programs:

- A = We win 2min/cycle
- B = We win 3min/cycle
- C = We win 2min/cycle
- D = We win 16min/cycle
  We make 50 cycle per day.

But the problem for my Mathematical formula is : A program is not used as much as the others :

- 79 % Program A
- 6 % Program B
- 5 % Program C
- 11 % Program D

So i want determinate how mins/hours i win per day.

I didn't ask to resolve my calcul, but a mathematical formula for do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean something like $50 \times \sum_{i=1}^n (P[X=i] \times W_i)$, with $X, i$ the type of program and $W_i$ the minutes won by this program?

Comment: I've try this but i didn't use the percent use program in this equation.

Comment: Filling in the specific values you mentioned, the above formula evaluates to $50 \times (0.79 \times 2 + 0.06 \times 3 + 0.05 \times 2 + 0.11 \times 16) = 181$.

Comment: Oh, i didn't understand this :) Thank you a lot